# Exe to download without prompt either execute or put itself on startup folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, exe, malware

I have url which doesn't promt for download on any browser and put itself on startup folder file type is .exe  Is it possible ? Then How ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, but I'm pretty sure it belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

hmmt.. it's look like you want to build malware ha ? :D

i think, download file without prompt is impossible except your victim already set default download folder.

direct put your file to startup folder is immpossible except your victim already execute your file which have malcode to create some file in startup folder.

the above logic only work if your victim don't have any guard , like firewall and anti virus.

then you need to learn code how to create file, etc depends on what you need and what is programming language to use.

anyway all above is really really really basic logic to malcode. :D

nice to meet you :D